# How to get webp image size from URL in iOS？

Tags: objective-c, webp

I tried to use `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL` method like below, but it seems both height and width are equal `0`. Is there any other way to get webp image from url?

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageUrl, NULL);
NSDictionary* imageHeader = (__bridge NSDictionary*) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
NSLog(@"Image header %@",imageHeader);
NSLog(@"PixelHeight %@",[imageHeader objectForKey:@"PixelHeight"]);
NSNumber* height = [imageHeader objectForKey:@"PixelHeight"];
NSNumber* width = [imageHeader objectForKey:@"PixelWidth"];
```

Comment: How are you determining the height and width from the CGImageSourceRef? Are you using `CGImageSourceCopyProperties` or something else? Creating a CGImageSource doesn't actually load the data, so it's not going to know the height and width until you actually fetch something.

Comment: yeah, i can get jpg or png url image size by using using CGImageSourceCopyProperties but not webp url image

Answer (score 0):

The webp format image is not supported in iOS. You can use URLSession to fetch image data, then use it to create NSImage with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage).

Comment: so which means i have no way to get webp format image from url without downloading it in ios

Comment: Yes, the CGImageSourceCreateWithURL also downloads the entire image so I think there is no big difference.